# Using MJML in conjunction with Litmus Builder / partials and snippets

Tags: email, code-snippets, partials, mjml, litmus

I'm wondering if anyone has some insight on this topic. My team and I have been using MJML to create a large library of emails. Everyone is trained to use MJML, but I'm thinking about re-factoring things so we can use the Litmus builder instead so that we can take advantage of snippets and partials for a more dynamic email design/code experience.

We are constantly updating our headers and footers it seems, and I want to figure out a way that we can use global elements to update our emails, but still use MJML as a framework somehow.

Has anyone figured out a way to do such a thing?

I would like to avoid having to build these emails with straight raw tables, TD's and TR's, simply because not everyone on our team understands how to code emails this way.

Thoughts?

We use Litmus for testing regularly, but would like to learn how to use MJML framework in conjunction with the Litmus Builder tools such as partials and snippets.